# Move data from a database cluster to another

Tags: postgresql, deployment, database-migration

In a short time, I will deploy the first version of my web app online. I am using a PostgreSQL database for this project. I have two different choices as database clusters to use: Planescale PostgreSQL, which is free up to 5GB of space, or Digital Ocean cluster, which for 10 gigs costs about 12 dollars a month. The price is not that a big deal, but I think that for at least one year the 5GB plan is more than enough, given that my application will generate almost no revenue.

My question was, how hard can be to move all my data from Planetscale to DigitalOcean or to any other possible provider in the future if more space is needed? Can I do that almost painlessly or I put my data in danger is better to start paying now and don't have problems in the future?

If you have suggestions or recommendations, please, you are welcome

Comment: pg_dump/pg_restore

Comment: Can you explain more in detail, or add some links, please? Thank you a lot

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup.html https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html

Comment: But do I need the CLI? If I am using sort of the UI of planetscale and Digital ocean does it work the same?